# Show total number of respondents in legend of pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to show the total number of respondents (345) in the legend. How can I do that?

- yes corresponds to 90 people
- no corresponds to 255 people

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = 'Yes', 'No'
sizes = [yes, no]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.title('People who used it before')
```

Comment: Do you mean that you currently have a legend which shows the numbers for "yes" and for "no", but not the total?

Comment: I have no legend right now. I would like to show the total number of respondents somewhere and I thought the legend would be a good place. But I don't know how to programme that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the total to the legend (along with the Yes/No), you could use the legend title to show this using something like `plt.legend(title=f'Total {len(sizes)}')`

Full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = 'Yes', 'No'
sizes = ['Yes']*90 + ['No']*255
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pie(pd.Series(sizes).value_counts(), labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.legend(title=f'Total {len(sizes)}')
plt.title('People who used it before')
```

[image]

**OPTION 2**

If all you want is the number and NOT the legend, you can simply add a `plt.text(...)` instead. Comment out the `plt.legend(...)` and add this line... I showing the options you can use... first is the x, y from bottom left, then the text to display, the font size, color and then the box with style, color and the transparency (alpha). Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
plt.text(0.8, 0.9, f'Total {len(sizes)}', fontsize=12, color='black', 
         bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering wether I could use something like plt.legend(title=f'N =' sizes) since I already defined sizes as "yes+no". Not sure if that is possible. I am pretty new to Python.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how you have defined yes and no, but assuming they are integers with values of 90 and 255, you can use something like `title=f'N = {yes+no}'` OR `title=f'N = {sizes}'`. The calculation like addition of two variables needs to be within the `{}`. That should work...

Comment: Perfekt! This is exactly what I meant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have one more question that came up. Can I get rid of the "Yes" and "No" so that I only get "Total 345" in the legend? I just want to somehow show the total number of participants somewhere. Maybe the legend is not a good place?

Comment: If all you need a text to show the total, you can comment out the legend and use plt.text() instead. Please check Option 2 for an example of the same....

Comment: Thank's what I wanted! Many, many thanks! I have learnt so much from you! Thank you very much!